# How to inherit mail template in odoo 16.0

Tags: odoo-16

How to inherit mail template correctly in odoo?

I'm trying to inherit mail template

I follow the [How to Inherit & Update an Existing Mail Template in Odoo 16](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-inherit-and-update-an-existing-mail-template-in-odoo-16)
to change name and subject for simple test.

This is what i have tried

```py
...
    'depends': ['base','auth_signup'],
    'data': [
        'data/mail_template.xml',
    ],
...
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
            <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
                <value eval="[('name', '=', 'mail_template_user_signup_account_created'), ('module', '=', 'auth_signup')]" />
            </function>
            <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
        </function>
        

        <!-- Email template for new users that used a signup token -->
        <record id="auth_signup.mail_template_user_signup_account_created" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Settings: New User Invite updated</field>
            <field name="subject">Hello {{ object.name }}: Welcome to {{ object.company_id.name }}!</field>
        </record>

        <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
            <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
                <value eval="[('name', '=', 'mail_template_user_signup_account_created'), ('module', '=', 'auth_signup')]" />
            </function>
            <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
        </function>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I restarted the server and updated the module, but it still doesn't work.

What i am doing bad?

Answer (score 0):

```
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('name','=','mail_template_user_signup_account_created'),('module','=','auth_signup')]"/>
    function>
    <value eval=" {'noupdate': False} "/>
function>

<record id="auth_signup.mail_template_user_signup_account_created" model="mail.template">        
   <field name="body_html" type="html">
     Here Mail Template Content.
   <field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. As you can see from the post, I have already done the steps mentioned in your answer and it doesn't work. any ideas?